# PHPMailer's `Body` does not do anything

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, phpmailer

I need to send emails with an attachment, and I chose PHPMailer for it. I found that I must use `Body` to make the attachment work, but my problem is that if I use it, the form is reloaded and the `if` condition to check if the email was sent was not even checked. The form reloads and nothing happend, it does not even reset the form as consisted in the JavaScript file.

Using `FormData` allows me to upload files using Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#FormularioContato').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'enviar.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            data: formData,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.tipo !== 'Erro') {
                    $("#FormularioContato")[0].reset();
                    $('#Msg').hide().removeClass().addClass(data.tipo).html(data.msg).fadeIn('slow').delay(7000).fadeOut('slow');
                } else {
                    $('#Msg').hide().removeClass().addClass(data.tipo).html(data.msg).fadeIn('slow').delay(7000).fadeOut('slow');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This is the piece of code to send the e-mail using PHPMailer:

```
$mensagem = '';
$mensagem .= 'Nome: ' . $_post['Nome'];
$mensagem .= 'Email: ' . $_post['Email'];
$mensagem .= 'Telefone Residencial: ' . $_post['Telefone Residencial'];
$mensagem .= 'Telefone Celular: ' . $_post['Telefone Celular'];
$mensagem .= 'Mensagem: ' . $_post['Mensagem'];

$extensoes = array('pdf', 'doc', 'docx');
$extensaoArquivo = pathinfo($_FILES['Arquivo']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$novoNomeArquivo = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '_', $_post['Nome']) . '.' . $extensaoArquivo);

if (in_array($extensaoArquivo, $extensoes)) {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Arquivo']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/' . $novoNomeArquivo)) {
        $mailer->ContentType = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8";
        $mailer->setFrom($_post['Email'], $_post['Nome']);
        $mailer->addAddress("email@example.com");
        $mailer->Subject = 'Trabalhe conosco - ' . $_post['Nome'];
        $mailer->isHTML(true)
        $mailer->Body($mensagem);
        $mailer->addAttachment($_FILES['Arquivo']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['Arquivo']['name']);

        if ($mailer->send()) {
            echo json_encode(array(
                'tipo' => 'Sucesso',
                'msg' => 'Mensagem enviada com sucesso.'
            ));
        } else {
            echo json_encode(array(
                'tipo' => 'Erro',
                'msg' => 'Ocorreu um erro ao enviar o e-mail.' . $mailer->ErrorInfo
            ));
        }
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array(
            'tipo' => 'Erro',
            'msg' => 'Ocorreu um erro ao enviar o anexo'
        ));
    }
} else {
    echo json_encode(array(
        'tipo' => 'Erro',
        'msg' => 'Arquivo de anexo inválido. Somente PDF, DOC ou DOCX'
    ));
}
```

Comment: If you're in an environment where you can, check your PHP Error log, on unix this is usually in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` and post the error produced after submitting the form.

Comment: From the symptoms it sound like you have attached the `.on('submit')` handler to the wrong element.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 It is right. The form `id` is that. It all works with `msgHTML`, it sends the e-mail successfully, the problem is just with `Body` that does nothing as I described.

Comment: @acupajoe Nothing there.

Comment: When you're looking for a bug, don't look at the end of the chain - start at the beginning, check your inputs before wondering about the results. There's nothing wrong with Body, it's just that by the time you set it, you've lost your data, and you need to figure out whre that is.

Comment: @mfgabriel92, you say that "... the form is reloaded ...", which is why I suggested the handler is attached to the wrong element. Do you mean "... the form is reset ..."?

Comment: Suggest you add a ajax error handler and see if it fires.

Comment: Please post your html form so we can see the inputs and the elements you are relating to! This may help to solve te problem. @Synchro say 'start at the beginning' and that is really TRUE.